# Can't show content text from menu using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I am trying to make a submenu using jQuery.  The idea is that when someone clicks on the first menu a submenu appears, then when someone clicks the submenu it disappears and shows a div with information but I cant make it work properly.

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="show1">Sub menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="show2">Sub menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="show1" class="content">Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an. </div>
<div id="show2" class="content">Ius id vidit volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos debet libris consulatu. No mei ferri </div>
```

And this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu li ').click(function () {
        $('#submenu').fadeToggle();
        $('.content').fadeOut();
    });
    $('ul#submenu li a').click(function () {
        var menu = $(this).data("menu");
        $('#' + menu).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

The idea is simple, if menu is clicked all the content divs must hide and the submenu must toggle (show if hidden, hide if shown.)  When a submenu item is clicked, the submenu must hide and the content div matching the data attribute clicked must appear.

But, when I click the submenu item it shows the content for a moment then it disappears.  Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yab34zdw/

Comment: Where is `.content` in your HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you click on a submenu item, both of those event handlers are being fired. The problem is with your selectors:

`$('#menu li ')` also captures the submenu items, which are also `<li>` tags that are descendants of the menu. You could just change the selector to `$("#menu > li")`, which captures only direct descendants (children), but I think in general its just better to add classes, and use simpler selectors.

HTML

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-top-item>
        <a class="menu-top-item-link" href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li class="menu-sub-item">
                <a class="menu-sub-item-link" href="#" data-menu="show1">Sub menu 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu-sub-item">
                <a class="menu-sub-item-link" href="#" data-menu="show2">Sub menu 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/53u2m2q2/)

```
$('.menu-top-item-link').click(function () {
    $('#submenu').fadeToggle();
    $('.content').fadeOut();
    return false;
});
$('.menu-sub-item-link').click(function () {
    var menu = $(this).data("menu");
    $('#' + menu).fadeIn();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: The submenu items are **descendants** of the menu, not children.

Comment: It doesnt work, it makes exactly the same, shows the content for a moment and then it dissapears...

Comment: @Chico3001 Sorry, I just noticed that I had one of the selectors still pointing to the `<li>` when it should have been pointing at the `<a>`. I've edited and added a Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks... that return false was missing and the problem, do you have any link explaining why? will be very appreciated

Comment: The `return false` isn't the issue. If you delete it from the fiddle it still behaves the same way. The problem was that I had the top menu link pointing at the `<li>` which encompasses everything. Clicking on a submenu item is still inside the top `<li>` so both handlers were still firing. `return false` is in there to cancel the navigation that the `<a>` should normally trigger. If you return false in a click handler on a link, it prevents the link from navigating the browser to its target. In your case, that's still the same page, but it prevents adding a hash to your URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got what you're going for but play around with this little tweak to see if it's closer to what you describe. I think both click functions were targeting your submenu content.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu .menu ').click(function () {
        $('#submenu').fadeToggle();
        $('.content').fadeOut();
    });
    $('ul#submenu li a').click(function () {
        var menu = $(this).data("menu");
        $('#' + menu).fadeToggle();
    });
})
```

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="menu">Item 1</a>
        <ul id="submenu">
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="show1">Sub menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" data-menu="show2">Sub menu 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="show1" class="content">Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an. </div>
<div id="show2" class="content">Ius id vidit volumus mandamus, vide veritus democritum te nec, ei eos debet libris consulatu. No mei ferri </div>
```